# Consulta mysql de Acordo com Array unserialize

Tags: php, mysql

Nesse select a baixo como posso fazer com que ele só retorne as linhas
com os ids que se encontrem nessa variável  ( $range ) essa variável esta retornando dados do banco vários ids

```
// estou utlizando a função unserialize
$range = unserialize ($linha["range_ids"]);     

$sql = "SELECT a.*, f.*,e.*,u.*,p.*, SUM(valor) AS 'soma'  FROM a_finan AS f 

LEFT JOIN agenda_saidas AS a
ON a.id_saida = f.id_saida
LEFT JOIN empresas AS e
ON e.id_empresa = f.id_empresa
LEFT JOIN usuarios AS u
ON u.id_user = f.user_soli
LEFT JOIN passageiros AS p
ON p.voucher = f.voucher


where f.id_transfer = '$id_transfer' and cod_bloco_faturamento = '$bloco' ";     
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

$bloco = $linha["cod_bloco_faturamento"];
$id_empresa = $linha["id_empresa"];
$valor1 = $linha["valor"];
$valor = 'R$' . number_format($valor1, 1, ',', '.');
$vencimento = $linha["data_vencimento"];
```

Comment: Quais são os valores nela contidos ?

Comment: eu estou inserindo esse dados 1052,1053,1054 mais estou inserindo no db atravez do "serialize'  que esta sendo gravado assim la a:3:{i:1052;s:4:"1052";i:1053;s:4:"1053";i:1054;s:4:"1054";}

Answer (score 0):

Na cláusula where você pode acrescentar o operador **IN**.

```
where f.id_transfer = '$id_transfer' and cod_bloco_faturamento = '$bloco' 
AND id_linha IN ('$range');"
```

No entanto quero acrescentar um alerta, visto que a execução do código da forma como está usando abre o select a um ataque do tipo SQL Injection.

Edit: Eu aconselharia a compor os selects usando o [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ou o [MYSQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)